# I would like to know the output voltage waveform across the resistor for a RC Differentiator circuit. The input signal is a bidirectional square wave

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

I would like to know the output voltage waveform across the resistor for an RC Differentiator circuit. The input signal is a bi-directional square wave.

I can't understand how the negative  input voltage affects the output waveform. I get how the positive part in the input voltage affects the input. it first charges the capacitor to the input voltage and then discharges till 0. the output voltage then drops to negative part even though the input is all positive..

But what happens during the negative part of the input voltage?

[image]

[image]

You may ignore the values of the resistor and capacitor.

Comment: with minimal research http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/electron/rc.htm

Comment: Thank You. But I can't understand how the negative  input voltage affects the output waveform. I get how the positive part  in the input voltage affects the input. it first charges the capacitor to the input voltage and then discharges till 0. the output voltage then drops to negative part even though the input is all positive..

But what happens during the negative part of the input voltage?

Comment: Could you please give me the output waveform in a diagram or explain the negative part to me.

Comment: The circuit only responds to change (the differential (dV/dt) of the function) - a positive  **edge** produces a positive going spike because dV/dt is positive, a negative **edge** produces a negative going spike because dV/dt is negative.

Comment: Thank You. I have a better grasp of the behaviour now. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jim Dearden: shouldn't C charge and discharge exponentially?

Comment: @Chu The basic rule for a capacitor is that you can't instantly change the voltage across the plates. A rising or falling edge causes the other plate of the capacitor to rise or fall by the same amount so that the voltage across the plates stays the same (a spike). Its at this point the other plate can either start to charge or discharge exponentially through R. Usually the time constant is chosen to be small in comparison to the pulse width which brings the function of the circuit closer to that of a perfect differentiator. Its all explained in my first comment's reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a differential circuit, I think you should elaborate further your question because you forgot to identify how much is the period of the rectangular signal and Amplitude As well ! for the circuit the time-constant is RC=1s and at the first edge the  out pout must be Vc+-Vc-= the amplitude of the impulse after that the output will decrease exponentially and so on.